# How to create a responsive table within a flex-grow container without affecting the overall layout?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I'm working on a responsive layout using Bootstrap 5.3 that includes a NavBar, SideBar, ContentPanel, and StatusBar. The app should be always 100% view-height and view-width and contain all information **without getting page scrollbars**!

The ContentPanel contains an element on the top, a table with dynamic values, and an element at the bottom. I want the table to be as tall as possible without pushing the element below it and the StatusBar outside the viewport!

When I have only a few rows it looks good, here an example:

[image: This is the layout I am aiming for. The ContentPanel should take up as much vertical and horizontal space as possible until without adding page scrollbars.]

My problems arises when the table get's many rows: the table pushes the element below and the StatusBar out of the viewport and the whole page get's a vertical scrollbar! Here an example:

[image: Too many rows push the Status Bar and the other element out of the viewport.]

When the table's content exceeds the ContentPanel's size, I want a scrollbar to appear **within** the table inside the ContentPanel, so you can scroll through the table rows without loosing sight of the StatusBar. The table should take up the remaining height of the ContentPanel after the other elements have been rendered.

So far, I was able to make this work only when I set a maximum height on the table, however then it becomes not as responsive, see here:

[[image: Vertical scrollbar does work when maximum height set, however, it is then not responsive and does not take up as much space as it should. 3]

Can somebody help me out? Here my StackBlitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/jyee1m?file=index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this if you set a fixed `height` to the status bar, which I guess will not vary in contact as much as the content panel. Then you add `max-height: calc(100vh - 27px);` to the content wrapper and Bootstrap class `overflow-auto` to the scrollable table so that the scrollbar appears inside the table and not for the whole page. Also, use `d-flex flex-column` on the content wrapper.

See the snippet below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .status {
      height: 25px;
    }
    
    .content {
      max-height: calc(100vh - 27px);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="m-0 p-0 border-0 bd-example bd-example-flex">
  <div class="vh-100 d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1">
      <nav class="border p-2">NavBar</nav>
      <aside class="border p-2">SideBar</aside>
      <div class="border p-2 flex-grow-1 content d-flex flex-column">
        ContentPanel

        <div class="above-table">Element above table</div>
        <div class="scrollable-table overflow-auto">
          <table class="table" class="table-responsive">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Username</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">2</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">3</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">4</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">5</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">6</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">7</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">8</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">9</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">10</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">11</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">12</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">13</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">14</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">15</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">16</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">17</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">18</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">19</th>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">20</th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>The Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">20</th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>The Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">20</th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>The Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">20</th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>The Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">20</th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>The Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">20</th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>The Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">20</th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>The Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">20</th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>The Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">20</th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>The Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">20</th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>The Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">20</th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>The Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">20</th>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>The Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="below-table">Element below table</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border status">StatusBar</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the quick reply!! Your solutions looks really clean... I actually also thought about calculating the height, however, I thought this might be not a very responsive and performing way to fix this issue (since the window can change a lot and also I need a fixed height). Any thoughts on this? Also for some reason, there still is a small vertical app scrollbar additionally to the table scrollbar. Any idea where this comes from?

Comment: @MikhailRatner My bad. The scrollbar appears because you also need to subtract all borders. So, if you set the `height` to `25px`, you need to subtract `27px`. Hm, I don't understand why that would not be a good solution. Can you explain?

Comment: Ah yes, of course! The borders... actually there are 4 relevant 1px borders, so we need even 29 px :) (just tested it).
Well, it is not a thorough explanation, but basically what just happened now. Instead of letting Bootstrap figuring out how high everything should be, it is me who has to calculate it. Which is totally fine for me now, but I wonder if this might cause issues at a later point, e.g. if somebody else directly or indirectly changes the height of the StatusBar.

Comment: Oh btw, what I did not fully grasp: why was adding ```d-flex flex-column``` on the content wrapper necessary for this to work??

Answer (score 1):

Apply `height: 100vh` to the `<div>` element that wraps the whole webpage via the `vh-100` class. With its vertical flex layout and this class, this can be used to limit the sizing of elements within.

We apply `min-height: 0` to various inner elements to override the `min-height: min-content` that would otherwise apply by default due to the vertical flex layouts.

We apply `max-height: 100%` via `mh-100`, and invoke a vertical flex layout to give the *ContentPanel* `<div>` a height constraint of its parent element, so that the inner `.scrollable-table` element will have a constraint to shrink to.

```css
.scrollable-table {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.min-h-0 {
  min-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/css/docs.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="m-0 p-0 border-0 bd-example bd-example-flex">
    <div class="vh-100 d-flex flex-column vh-100">
      <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1 min-h-0">
        <nav class="border p-2">NavBar</nav>
        <aside class="border p-2">SideBar</aside>
        <div class="border p-2 flex-grow-1 d-flex flex-column min-h-0 mh-100">
          ContentPanel

          <div>Element above table</div>
          <div class="scrollable-table min-h-0">
            <table class="table" class="table-responsive">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">#</th>
                  <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                  <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                  <th scope="col">Username</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">1</th>
                  <td>Mark</td>
                  <td>Otto</td>
                  <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">2</th>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">3</th>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">4</th>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">5</th>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">6</th>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">7</th>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">8</th>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">9</th>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">10</th>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">11</th>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">12</th>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">13</th>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">14</th>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">15</th>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">16</th>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">17</th>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">18</th>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">19</th>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">20</th>
                  <td>Larry</td>
                  <td>The Bird</td>
                  <td>@twitter</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div>Element below table</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="border">StatusBar</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow this looks exactly how I wanted it to look, THANKS  A LOT! But to be honest, I am a bit confused how this actually works... I had the vh-100 class, but I don't fully grasp why the elements inside the flex-grow-1 need .min-h-0!? Did this cause the issue, since the min-height of the elements took the min-height of the full content (which pushed the rest down)?

Comment: Btw I just applied your answer to the StackBlitz and I only need the very first ```.min-h-0```! Which makes it even more confusing to me  https://stackblitz.com/edit/jyee1m-lfzhsf?file=index.html